# Disable and select certain checkboxes using database values

Tags: php, html, checkbox, mysqli, disabled-input

I'm working on a reservation system for a cinema. I have a table called `Reservation` with columns: `movie_id`, `customer_id`, `seatnumbers` and `time_id`.

On the page where you can select the seats that you wanted, I'd like to disable and check the checkboxes who are already chosen (by other customers).

This is my seats.php file (the page where you choose the seats):

```
<form method="POST">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <?php 
            $rowSeats= 20;  // seat rows
            $Maxrows= 30;  // number of rows
            for($x=1; $x<=$Maxrows; $x++){
                echo '<div class="totalRow">';  // total rows
                    echo '<div class="rowSeat">'.$x.'</div>';
                    echo '<div class="GroupSeats">';  // group of seats
                        for($i = 1; $i <= $rowSeats; $i++){
                            if(($i % 4) ==1){
                                echo '</div>';
                                echo '<div class="GroupSeats">';  // group of seats
                            }
                            echo '<div class="singleSeat">';  // single seat
                                if(isset($_POST['chbseat']) && in_array($x.'-'.$i , $_POST['chbseat']) && count($_POST['chbseat']) == $_GET['amount_of_persons']){
                                    echo '<input class="button1" type="checkbox" value="'.$x. '-'. $i. '" checked  disabled name="chbseat[]" id="chbseat"/>';
                                }elseif(isset($_POST['chbseat']) && !in_array($x.'-'.$i , $_POST['chbseat']) && count($_POST['chbseat']) == $_GET['amount_of_persons']){
                                    echo '<input class="button1" type="checkbox" value="'.$x. '-'. $i. '" disabled name="chbseat[]" id="chbseat"/>';
                                }elseif(isset($_POST['chbseat']) && in_array($x.'-'.$i , $_POST['chbseat']) && count($_POST['chbseat']) != $_GET['amount_of_persons']){
                                    echo '<input class="button1" type="checkbox" value="'.$x. '-'. $i. '" checked name="chbseat[]" id="chbseat"/>';
                                }else{
                                    echo '<label><input class="button1" type="checkbox" value="'.$x. '-'. $i. '" name="chbseat[]" id="chbseat"/></label>';
                                }
                            echo '</div>';
                        }
                    echo '</div>';
                echo "</div>";  
            }   
            ?>              
        </tr>
    </table>
</form>
```

I'm not actually inserting it here. I will insert it later, when I have all the data that is needed for the table.

I manually added some reservations(with seatnumbers) to the database so there is data.

So to be clear: The checkboxes that are already chosen needs to be selected and disabled. Every seat has his own value what can be the value in the database. In my database is insert that value. Something like: 6-12 (row 6, seat 12)

Comment: Instead of pasting your whole file, please only include the relevant block of code.  I also cannot translate your comments/attributes/etc to English.  If `FILM.ID`  is an integer, please at the very least protect your query with `intval($filmid)` What exactly isn't working for you?

Comment: you want check and uncheck the boxes based on the values from db?

Comment: @mickmackusa I removed the unnecessary stuff. The thing that isn't working is: I don't understand how to disable and check the selectbox that has the value what is based on the database value

Comment: @2by2 Yeah thats it!

Comment: I have edited your question.  Please re-edit it to add the necessary code where you tried to integrate your database information with your form.  Show us some database column values.  Please be very clear about the outcome you wish to produce given some sample input.   (translating any of your Dutch words to English will be very helpful for English readers)

Comment: I changed it. Is this better? @mickmackusa

Comment: What is the data in the `seatnumbers` column?  Is it a comma-separated-value?  Are there 20 rows of 30 seats?  600 values in your seatnumbers fields? I hope you are continuing your efforts to self-solve.  If you make progress, you should update your question.  At this point, you have a "project" not a "problem".